# Read file names from directory

Tags: php

I am trying to read and display all the files in a directory using this code.
It works fine for files in the same directory as the script. But when I try to display files in a folder (files/) it is giving me problems.

I've tried setting the directoy variable to many different things. like...
files/
files
/files/
etc... nothing seems to work. Does anyone have any idea why?

```
<?php
$dhandleFiles = opendir('files/');
$files = array();

if ($dhandleFiles) {
    while (false !== ($fname = readdir($dhandleFiles))) {
        if (is_file($fname) && ($fname != 'list.php') && ($fname != 'error.php') && ($fname != 'index.php')) {
            $files[] = (is_dir("./$fname")) ? "{$fname}" : $fname;
        }
    }
    closedir($dhandleFiles);
}

echo "Files";
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($files as $fname) {
    echo "<li><a href='{$fname}'>{$fname}</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Comment: What is the directory structure relative to this script? Is the "files" directory inside the same folder as this script?

Comment: Correct, the files dir is in the same level as the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help - take a look at [SplFileInfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) too.

```
<?php
class ExcludedFilesFilter extends FilterIterator {
    protected
        $excluded = array(
            'list.php',
            'error.php',
            'index.php',
        );
    public function accept() {
        $isFile     = $this->current()->isFile();
        $isExcluded = in_array($this->current(), $this->excluded);

        return $isFile && ! $isExcluded;
    }
}

$dir = new DirectoryIterator(realpath('.'));

foreach (new ExcludedFilesFilter($dir) as $file) {
    printf("%s\n", $file->getRealpath());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not including the full path in your array:

```
while($fname = readdir($dhandleFiles)) {
    $files[] = 'files/' . $fname;
               ^^^^^^^^---must include actual path
}
```

Remember that readdir() returns **ONLY** the filename, without path information.

Answer (score 1):

How about using glob function.

```
<?php
define('MYBASEPATH' , 'files/');
foreach (glob(MYBASEPATH . '*.php') as $fname) {
    if($fname != 'list.php' && $fname != 'error.php' && $fname != 'index.php') {
        $files[] = $fname;
    }
}
?>
```

[read more about getting all files in directory here](http://www.denbag.us/2013/10/how-to-include-all-php-files.html)

Answer (score 1):

This reads and prints filenames from a sub-directory:

```
$d = dir("myfiles");
while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
  if ($entry != ".") {
    if ($entry != "..") {
        print"$entry";       
    }
  }
}
$d->close();
```